# How to implemement custom markup trigger for prettyPhoto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, prettyphoto

Firstly, I have this view on table:
[image]

when I click the `td`, it opens the PrettyPhoto Lightbox

on prettyPhoto, the default html trigger is:

```html
<a href="images/fullscreen/2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is the description">
    <img src="images/thumbnails/t_2.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="This is the title" />
</a>
```

but instead I have this html:

```html
<a href="image.jpeg" data-rel="prettyPhoto" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" class="kt-user-card-v2">
    <div class="kt-user-card-v2__pic">
        <img src="http://wasapbro-2019.test/storage/msg/cupb1RUgcGLnUovQi7eBpxLIIRu37sPKcha1jjuI.jpeg" class="m-img-rounded kt-marginless" alt="photo">
    </div>
    <div class="kt-user-card-v2__details">
        <span class="kt-user-card-v2__name">test</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

on mine that fails to trigger

How do I solve this?

Comment: a cheap way to do it could be to have another img tag before dive kt-user-card-v2__pic and hide it by making display for the img to none

Comment: could you show me a code/runnable example or illustration for that?

Comment: sure, I will write an answer

Comment: sorry that way my only idea. I have it worked with this before.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are initializing PrettyPhoto, but I set up this quick demo using your DOM structure and it seems to work just fine.  One thing to note is that you need to use jQuery version 2.x or older since PrettyPhoto relies on .size(); which isn't available in jQuery 3.0+.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Pretty Photo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://lib.arvancloud.com/ar/prettyPhoto/3.1.6/css/prettyPhoto.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://lib.arvancloud.com/ar/prettyPhoto/3.1.6/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="https://live.staticflickr.com/8183/8079715772_f003d725d1_z.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" class="kt-user-card-v2">
                    <div class="kt-user-card-v2__pic">
                        <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/8183/8079715772_f003d725d1_z.jpg" class="m-img-rounded kt-marginless" alt="photo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="kt-user-card-v2__details">
                        <span class="kt-user-card-v2__name">test</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="https://live.staticflickr.com/8512/8509212953_4cfefc8b9a_z.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" class="kt-user-card-v2">
                    <div class="kt-user-card-v2__pic">
                        <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/8512/8509212953_4cfefc8b9a_z.jpg" class="m-img-rounded kt-marginless" alt="photo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="kt-user-card-v2__details">
                        <span class="kt-user-card-v2__name">test</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```